# How to send file from client to server using (OCSF)

Tags: java, client-server

He,
I am building a client-server project, where the server can connet to multtiple clients at once, in my project I'm using the (OCSF) framework, and i'm using the handleMessageFromClient method to handle messages from the clients, and sending messages to sever with the sendMessageToServer.
How can i send a file from client to server and save the file in server.

this is the code for server side:

```
public void handleMessageFromClient(Object msg, ConnectionToClient client){

    if(msg instanceof File){
        File file = (File)msg;

    }else if(msg instanceof HashMap<?, ?>){
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        HashMap<String, String> clientMsg = (HashMap<String, String>) msg;

        // shows the received msg to the event log
        logController.showMsg("Message received: " + clientMsg.get("msgType") + " from " + client);


        //check the msg type
        if(clientMsg.get("msgType").equals("Login")){
            login(clientMsg,client);
        }else if(clientMsg.get("msgType").equals("select")){
            selectQuery(clientMsg, client);
        }else if(clientMsg.get("msgType").equals("update")){
            updateQuery(clientMsg, client);
        }else if(clientMsg.get("msgType").equals("delete")){
            updateQuery(clientMsg, client);
        }else if(clientMsg.get("msgType").equals("insert")){
            updateQuery(clientMsg, client);
        }
    }
}
```

the client

```
final public void sendToServer(Object msg) throws IOException{
if (clientSocket == null || output == null)
      throw new SocketException("socket does not exist");

output.writeObject(msg);
output.reset();}
```

how can i modify the code to send and recive file??

i have the server and client code on github:
[client code](https://github.com/samerkinaan92/Academic-system-Client)
[sever code](https://github.com/samerkinaan92/Academic-system-Server)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by converting the file to byte array and sending it to the server as an Object.